# What is the standard matrix of $T^{101}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Be $R$ the line from the equation $y=-x$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and be $T:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ the reflection respect to the line $R$:

$T\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ -1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ -1
\end{pmatrix}$

and

$T\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ -1
\end{pmatrix}$

**Question:** What is the standard matrix of $T^{2}$? And for $T^{101}$?

Comment: There exists a shortcut to calculate $T^{101}$?

Comment: Hint : Diagonalize $T$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If we reflect through the same line twice, what are we left with?

Comment: Can I say that $T^{101}=T^{101\ mod\ 2}=T^{1}$?

Comment: Sure, that's one way to put it.  Indeed, $T^{101} = T$.  What about $T^{2}$?

Comment: I found that the standard matrix of T^{2} is $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$. And $T^{101}=T\circ (T^{2})^{50}$

Comment: Right. Just checking.